# Is it possible to evaluate an expression before being used as a function name?

Tags: php, class, variables, object, dynamic

I've run into a problem which has a simple solution...

```
$this->controller = new "controllers\\" . $namespace . $controller($this->relativePath);
```

I would like to do something like the above, but it doesn't work because it seems the value of the concatenated string is evaluated **after** `$controller($this->relativePath)` is evaluated.

The solution is something like this...

```
$x = "controllers\\" . $namespace . $controller
$this->controller = new $x($this->relativePath);
```

But it kills me to have a single-use variable. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Not tried it, and personally I don't have an issue with using a single-use variable; but what about brace-wrapping like something like `$this->controller = new {"controllers\\" . $namespace . $controller}($this->relativePath);`

Comment: Neither kind of braces work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the PHP engine to evaluate a string and execute it using `eval()`...most interpreted languages have such a function. I must warn you though, this can be very dangerous if your code is not absolutely correct because the PHP engine cannot be sure that what you are evaluating is proper PHP code. Thus, you will lose some safety that the engine offers when you use that. But if you know what you are doing, this should not deter you from using it; it was meant for this very purpose.

`$this->controller = eval("new controllers\\" . $namespace . $controller($this->relativePath));`

If the evaluation order is wrong...use parenthesis to convey your intentions; they have the highest precedence.

[Eval Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

**My Personal Recommendation**

Use the [Strategy Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Comment: I never mentioned that most of the time, with a bit of ingenuity you can usually avoid using `eval`.  The design pattern you are trying to implement is called a [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Its very common and I suggest using a more idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 1):

if you *definitely* don't want to use a second variable, you could instead use reflections:

```
<?php
function createObject($name, $params = null) {
    if($params == null) {
        return (new ReflectionClass($name))->newInstance();
    } else {
        return (new ReflectionClass($name))->newInstanceArgs($params);
    }
}


$instance = createObject("your"."classname", ["parameters"]);
```

one could test how it holds up against `eval` performance-wise, but since this can only instanciate objects (in contrast to eval, which can arbitrarily execute code), this *could* provide a security benefit.
you could also expand the function to limit it to certain namespaces etc.